# Davmail - no jfxwebkit in java.library.path

Tags: ubuntu

I get error:

```
ERROR [JavaFX Application Thread] davmail.exchange.auth.O365InteractiveAuthenticatorFrame  - java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jfxwebkit in java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jni, /usr/lib/alpha-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/x86_64-kfreebsd-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/powerpc64-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/s390x-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/sparc64-linux-gnu/jni] no jfxwebkit in java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jni, /usr/lib/alpha-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/x86_64-kfreebsd-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/powerpc64-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/powerpc64le-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/s390x-linux-gnu/jni, /usr/lib/sparc64-linux-gnu/jni]
```

But I have these packages installed on Kubuntu 20.04.

```
$ dpkg -l | grep open...
ii  openjdk-11-jre:amd64
ii  openjdk-11-jre-headless
ii  openjfx
ii  openjfx-source
```

How do I fix the path issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjfx/+bug/1877000), libopenjfx-jni ubuntu package does not contain libjfxwebkit.so. I've solved the issue by installing this [libopenjfx-jni](https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libopenjfx-jni)

Comment: Hmm. This has not helped me on Ubuntu 20.04. libopenjfx-jni already installed but the same failure from davmail ... Actually the bug discussion seems to indicate that not every version of libopenjfx-ini works.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: On 2020-10-11 I have updated my Ubuntu 20.04 packages (after fixing the problems introduced by the procedure below).  I landed with davmail  5.4.0-trunk, which is older than the mainline 5.5.1 but sufficiently new for talking to my exchange server.  This packaging is unable to open the web authentication, but the proxy mechanism (with link for a standard browser and pasting the token back) works, without any libopenjfx issues.  I just followed davmail gui instructions and I am operational.  So I do not use the (crippled) procedure below anymore.

---

Ivanoff's answer is actually useful, but I found it confusing so a slower version for everybody, who is a bit dense, like I am.  The debian's version of libopenjfx-ini does seem to solve the problem temporarily. So here is the procedure:

1. Install davmail from apt: `sudo apt install davmail` --- this gives an old version which, I cannot use, but ensures that most dependencies are in place.
2. Get `davmail_5.5.1-3299-1_all.deb` from davmail's homepage and use dpkg to upgrade to this version:

   `sudo dpkg -i davmail_5.5.1-3299-1_all.deb`

   This version will fail on an attempt to open the authentication window with no jfxwebkit in java library path error.
3. Download the file libopenjfx-jni_11.0.7+0-5_amd64.deb from https://packages.debian.org/sid/amd64/libopenjfx-jni and install it with dpkg:

   `sudo dpkg -i libopenjfx-jni_11.0.7+0-5_amd64.deb`

   This will fail with the following error message:

   ```
   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopenjfx-jni: libopenjfx-jni depends on libjpeg62-turbo (>= 1.3.1); however:
   Package libjpeg62-turbo is not installed.
   ```

   but davmail 5.5.1 will now work.

This can work with other versions.  I just gave you the combination of versions that works for me. Unfortunately, this leaves apt in an unstable state, complaining that I need to fix libopenjfx-ini first before I can use it with `--fix-broken install`.  This unfortunately reverses the entire procedure (removes `davmail libopenjfx-java libopenjfx-jni openjfx`). The only workaround I know for now is to fix whenever I need to use apt and then follow the steps above again afterwards.  Probably some apt/dpkg magic could help to avoid the hassle.

EDIT: The packaging bug is now apparently fixed (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjfx/+bug/1877000) but this has not been back ported to focal (20.04). Let's hope this happens in not too distant future, so that we do not have to suffer this mess for a long time.